# Ineffective bundle template override

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I've a problem to override the template of one of my bunddle. I've read the doc and try like this link : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html

Here what the state of my project : 
https://pasteboard.co/IarWJoZ4.png
I've add the path than I think is right : templates/bundles/AiemosShopBundle/views/Catalog but it doesn't work.

This is what template is calling in symfony debugger :

```
vendor/aimeos/aimeos-symfony/Resources/views/Catalog/list.html.twig
```

I've made multiple ineffective tests with paths like :
aiemos/aiemos-symfony

Could you help me to solve my problem or show me the right way to do this please?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Please post your code as code, not as a screenshot. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

> templates/bundles/AiemosShopBundle/views/Catalog but it doesn't work.

The correct folder is :

```
templates/bundles/AimeosShopBundle/Catalog
```

No **views** subfolder. Note that it is **AimeosShopBundle** instead of **AiemosShopBundle**

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I've made change in my path in removing the views but it still doesn't display my override...
I just checked my bundle name and it is 'AimeosShopBundle' as I wrote in path so my actual path is : templates/bundles/AiemosShopBundle/Catalog/list.html.twig

Comment: Thank you for your help,  I've already clean my cache with a : 
php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=dev

Comment: I think there is a typo in your code, the correct name is : "AimeosShopBundle" not "AiemosShopBundle"

So it's not :
"templates/bundles/AiemosShopBundle/Catalog/list.html.twig"
it should be :
"templates/bundles/AimeosShopBundle/Catalog/list.html.twig"

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake when I write it but in my project it was well write.